# Finding the correct mathmatics based on application as opposed to the other way around?

Tags: student-motivation, concept-motivation

I just tried to pitch a [Math Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106276/math-recommendations) site, and it was shot down because it is too broad and that Stack Exchange sites operate on a separation of concerns principle; which makes sense to me but doesn't solve a problem I've been looking to solve since I went to school taking math classes.

When I was in school as I remember it the issue wasn't that I didn't like math, it was actually that the problems in the math book didn't apply to anything that I was actually interested in at the time; and therefore I didn't realize how important math actually was to everyday life.

So it seems to me that one of the issues in educating people about math comes from the fact that there isn't a place where they can take their real world problems (i.e. things they care about) and find out what specific mathematical concepts they need to learn to fix their particular issue, or apply it to something they care about.

I did eventually find something that applied to me in the form of creating video games in computer programming that made me care about math, but I'm sure there are other people out there different from myself that have similar needs but are unaware of it, and I was wondering if there was a site or community of a similar nature to what I am proposing where answers to these Math Recommendation questions are what types of math you should learn (including pre-requisites) and examples of using it to solve the stated problem; this would then allow the question asker to study up and eventually understand the mathematical concepts they need to solve a problem that they care about.

Can you recommend such a site, or a tag related to this within the existing Stack Exchanges?

P.S. This may be more of a meta question, but I don't see a meta site, and nobody would answer this question on the Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Here is the meta site: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think your question is more appropriately posted at the meta site.

Comment: I often see questions like you mentioned and questions about recommendations for books on certain topics here: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath

Comment: @leeand00 I believe that "one of the issues in educating people about math" is to decide what one means about math: a "utilitarian" way of thinking? a "model theoretic" way of thinking, a "game theoretic" way of thinking?